# What was this short story about competing light bulb salesmen?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read in a collection. I'm wanting to say it was a "Year's Best Scifi & Fantasy Short Stories" or something like that from some time in the 2000 to 2015 range, but I'm not certain of that.

The story is about two salesmen selling special lightbulbs. One of the salesmen (let's say Bob) was definitely evil, selling bulbs intended to awaken/summon some horrible monstrosity (similar to various Lovecraftian elder gods). The other salesman (let's say Charlie) was selling bulbs that I think were intended to summon some other rival evil, though it's possible they were merely intended to block the other salesman's bulbs from working. One of the bulbs shone brightly but strangely, while the other actually produced darkness (though it may have been weird darkness that people could see through?).

The story ends with Charlie realizing Bob has tricked him somehow: maybe replacing Charlie's stock of bulbs with Bob's so he was actually selling the enemy's bulbs without realizing it, or following him a few houses back and buying Charlie's bulbs at higher than their selling price and throwing his own bulbs in for free (since neither is in this to make money). As he realizes this, the light in the area changes and Bob's god starts to enter the world.

Comment: And where's Alice while all this is going on? :-)

Comment: @DavidW Down the rabbit hole, obviously.